# Content page not displaying images

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer-2010

I have a project with a master page at the root level and multiple content pages which are at the root level as well.  Everything has been looking fine until I created a new folder and put a new content page in that folder.  None of the images are displaying for that particular page.  I'm sure its something simple that I'm missing.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SupertonesInstallation.aspx.cs" Inherits="Articles_SupertonesInstallation" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Home" Runat="Server">
content
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: How are you displaying the images?

Comment: Can you put your code?

Comment: In my masterpage my image is: <img id="cover_image" src="Images/07 WRX/cover.JPG" alt="wrx" />  This works for pages at root level but not content page in seperate folder